# create a unique Hyperledger admin card and settings

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to create a Hyperledger composer data starting from scratch using yeoman system. I can start the system using

```
yo Hyperledger-composer:nameOfBusiness
```

at the terminal.

How do I proceed from this?
I want to create my own admin and peer settings between multiple computer. I have searched some tutorials, but they are always business card built in. 
How do I create my own unique crypto config and crypto materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest working with the Fabric tutorial [Building Your First Network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html), then you will have background for the steps you need to create your own Custom Fabric.  This tutorial simulates a Multi-Org Fabric running on a single development machine, so you will then need to investigate networking for the multi machine config.   Multi machine connectivity of Docker Containers is usually handled with Kubernetes or Docker Swarm so you would need to use one of those.

Composer is a layer on top of Fabric so when the Fabric is running you can add Composer, and the [Multi Org tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial) shows the steps needed for Composer to work with a Multi-Org Fabric.

Comment: I did try that fabric tutorial. I feel that it is too hard to understand for me. Is there any good way to develop using composer? composer is more easy to understand and use. But there are many syntax and unknown function that I haven't understand that is used inside the script command. I did connect two Hyperledger composer instances using two Macs. But I want to know more on what can I do and what the settings means.